# Need to add email click tracking - to our application

Tags: javascript, email, .net, email-server

A small part of my software needs to send out emails.  I could really do with adding tracking capability, to see when links are clicked (and who clicked them). I could add this myself (via VBA/.Net/Javascript etc), but it would be crude and I'd much rather use a service that's designed for this (via REST GET/POST commands etc).

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where I work, we typically use a transactional email service like [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/). SendGrid can send real-time notifications about events that happen on the SendGrid system to a URL. These events include clicks, opens, unsubscribe, bounces, and many others. These events include more data than what SendGrid records and allow customers to customize their own reporting.

Further reading

- https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/index.html
- https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/tracking/#click-tracking